# My text Boxes is not getting filled

Tags: c#, database, windows, datatable, textbox

I have a pop up window with some check boxes and text boxes inside it.
What i am trying to do is that when my window is opened if my query will find info in the database the text box inside the window fill with the found info.

```
 public void showRadWindow(string radWindowClientID)   
    {
        string NO= "";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        NO= radNumTxb_NO.Value.ToString().Trim();


        string script = string.Format("function ShowRadWindow() {{ $find(\"{0}\").show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(ShowRadWindow); }} Sys.Application.add_load(ShowRadWindow);",
                        radWindowClientID);

        dt = clsQuery.getMother(NO);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)    // if mother name is found
        {
            txbMother.Text = dt.Rows[0]["mother_name"].ToString();
            txbMother.ReadOnly = true;
        }
        //else
        //{

        //}
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "ShowRadWindow", script, true);

        return;
    }
```

this is my code but for some reasons that i do not know the text box is not getting filled, and even the ReadOnly condition is not fulfilled.
Any idea why? where i am doing wrong?

Comment: what does the debugger tell you about the value of `dt.Rows[0]["mother_name"].ToString()` ?

Comment: @Mong ZHU it is found, and when i use Quick Watch for txbMother.Text i see that the value is assigned. But when the load is finished i the window is opened there is nothing in the text box.